# Google Maps as background

Tags: html, google-maps, css

Is there a sexy way to get a web page with Google Maps (in fullscreen), and just a small div#header on the top and a small div#container on the middle?

I had make some research and I had found this example: http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/exam/index.html ... but this is not exactly what I would like to do.

If you have a thin code example of a nice website example, this would help me a lot.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can position HTML elements randomly on top of a (HTML based) Google Map using `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. You just need to give them a `z-index` higher than that of any element in the Google map.

Untested but something along these lines should work:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .Overlay { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; 
             right: 0px; height: 50px; background-color: white; z-index: 100 }
</style>

... Fullscreen Google Map (or whatever)..... 

<div class="Overlay">I'm on top of a Google Map!</div>
```

Comment: @Pekka I am embedded the map in a iframe, can i use the position: fixed?

Answer (score 1):

If you hold the iframe for Google maps in a `div` with `position: relative`, and make the `div` the same dimensions as the iframe, you can then use `position: absolute` on other elements within the relatively positioned `div` to overlay them where you want on the GMap. You may need to tinker with the `z-index` css property of the content you wish to position over GMap.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice writeup of how it's done:

http://blog.wadehammes.com/post/3837158298

Comment: a problem i have with this solution is that if there is a need to scroll, the map does not stretch out and it's left an ugly white space when you scroll down